# Javascript - Chart.js with responsive gradient line filling

Tags: javascript, charts, gradient, responsive

When I generate line chart in fullscreen window, shown colors are in declared radius, however when I try to resize window, chart is resized properly however gradient colors are messed up. I try to solve this problem via listeners, however it doesn't work.

Anyone got ideas?

Here is my code:

```
var chrt = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = chrt.getContext("2d");
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(300, 0, 300, 600);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'black');
gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'orange');
gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'yellow');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'green');
mycanvas.addEventListener("resize", gradient_declaration);

function gradient_declaration() {
    var w = mycanvas.innerWidth;
    var h = mycanvas.innerHeight;
    if (gradient) { gradient.destroy(); } else {
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(w / 2, 0, w / 2, h);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'black');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'red');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'orange');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'yellow');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'green');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It's probably too late for you, but I came across the same issue.
the way I solved it was to create an inline plugin that will recalculate the gradient everytime the layout changes eg (resizing, data changing, etc)

```
var chart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [
    {
      id: "responsiveGradient",

      afterLayout: function(chart, options) {
        var scales = chart.scales;

        // create a linear gradient with the dimentions of the scale
        var color = chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(
          scales["x-axis-0"].left,
          scales["y-axis-0"].bottom,
          scales["x-axis-0"].right,
          scales["y-axis-0"].top
        );
        // add gradients stops
        color.addColorStop(0, "black");
        color.addColorStop(0.25, "red");
        color.addColorStop(0.5, "orange");
        color.addColorStop(0.75, "yellow");
        color.addColorStop(1, "green");
        // changes the background color option
        chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = color;
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Whoever encounter errors right here, for me `scales["x"]` & `scales["y"]` instead of `scales["x-axis-0"]` & `scales["y-axis-0"]` fixed the issue